# Flutter Update WidgetsFlutterBinding

Tags: flutter, updates

before the Flutter update today my app ran OK, now get:  If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.

Any ideas? E/flutter (29270): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.

I am using : import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

```
void main() async {
  await di.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Where di.init() initialises the bloc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution online:

Just put this row on the top of the main function:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Comment: Thanks and this worked first time. A good example of being a member of Stack Overflow

Comment: this very first line of main() but not working.any update on this??

Comment: @msayubi76 same here